# How to detect custom html tags and replace with html special char using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my below code. I am using Jquery command to insert below html.

```
<b>test</b><test@domain.com>    
$("span").html("<b>test</b><test@domain.com>")
```

Here i need output like this: **test**<test@domain.com>.

But now i got output like this: **test**.

Please help me to solve this problem. How can i detect that custom html tags and replace with &lt and &gt or any other way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<` by `&lt;` and `>` by `&gt;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Jknm/)

OR if you can use php,

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<test@domain.com>')?>
```

Except that I don't think you can surpass your custom html tags!

Comment: yes it will work. But b tag also affected. Here i need only for <test@domain.com> using jquery. And one more things "<b>test</b><test@domain.com>" this is dynamic text is given by user in textarea box.